# OpenShift & SwiftMail email authentication on remote site only

Tags: openshift

I am trying to send email via my gmail account and cannot find a solution to this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at .....

If I run my website on localhost (using win7, IIS Express and WebMatrix) my code works and the email is delivered. So my problem appears to be a possible configuration problem or misunderstanding on my part with OpenShift.

I have tried both port 465/SSL and 587/TLS and neither work on uploaded code.

Let me know what information to post to help track this problem down.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your gmail account security settings, it's work for me. There is no other issue it will be..cheers!